# 403 Forbidden Error on Mac when trying to view local files using Apache

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm experiencing a problem where I am unable to view local image files, such as a favicon .ico, .png, .svg .gif or .jpg when running apache locally.  I'm using apache 2.2.26, and I am setup on a Mac using the Sites folder.  Everything is running perfectly smoothly and I can even view images within my PHP and html files locally but when I type them in directly into the browsers URL field I get this error:

**Forbidden


You don't have permission to access /kitten.jpg on this server.**

If I try to go to a .php file or a .html file I get no such error.  The page renders just fine, and like I said, if the page has image files it pulls up everything as visible.  This is a minor problem since it only prevents me from seeing my favicon and from looking at images in the URL field of my browser, but it's something that I'm very curious as to why this is happening.  I've checked the permissions on my files and see nothing remarkable about these particular image files.  It seems that there must be something funny with the configuration files (perhaps httpd.conf?  or my user.conf file?).  I'm not an apache expert and any help would be appreciated.  I've also tried looking this up in other posts on stackoverflow and although other people may have a *similar* problem as I have it never seems to be this *particular* problem, so I'm hesitant to move forward with those subsequent solutions.  Hence my question about this specific issue.  Help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How do you type the url? What about .htaccess?

Comment: http://localhost/kitten.jpg

Comment: But you can get that image showing from your html/php page? What's the url if you right click->view image?

Comment: Good call.  Thank you. This helps but also adds to the mystery...Some images actually do run in the field, when I put them through a local copy of WordPress, for some reason.  I'll return with with more info.

Comment: There is an @symbol in the terminal on the permissions of the ones that apache **won't** let me see and no @ symbol on the permissions of the ones that apache **allows** me to view.  Could this mean something?

Comment: Oh derp...I figured it out

Comment: Permissions problems...lol.

Answer (score 2):

Can you browser your DocumentRoot? like this:

```
cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/
```

if you can ls your Documents, you do this:

```
sudo chown -R www-default:www-default /Library/WebServer/Documents
```

or

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /Library/Webserver/Documents
```

if you can not ls the doucument and you get the "permission" error, you should use root and set 
user and groud for yours. or set 755 Permission